# Paginate self referencing relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel app that has a "Word" eloquent model. It has 2 relationships defined like this:

```
    /**
     * Synonyms for this word
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function synonyms() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Word::class, 'synonyms', 'word_id', 'synonym_id');
    }

    /**
     * Words that have this word as their synonym
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function isSynonymFor() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Word::class, 'synonyms', 'synonym_id', 'word_id');
    }
```

To make the relationships do their thing, i use a pivot table.

What i want to do is get the synonyms of a given array of words (strings). I think i can do that like this.

```
Word::whereHas('isSynonymFor', function(Builder $query) use($wordsArray) {
    $query->whereIn('name', $wordsArray);
})->simplePaginate();
```

I did not try that yet since something confuses me. Because of the self referencing relationship, i cannot wrap my head arround how it should word. I think because the words i want synonyms for are referenced in both synonym_id and word_id columns of the pivot table.

How do i use the relationships to retrieve all synonyms for a given array of words and paginate those. Do i need to use both relationshops to never miss a synonym?

I hope i make a little bit of sense since i am having a hard time understanding the problem itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query should look something like below, where you also need to consider the reverse relationship.

```php
Word::whereHas('isSynonymFor', function(Builder $query) use ($wordsArray) {
    $query->whereIn('name', $wordsArray);
})->orWhereHas('synonyms', function(Builder $query) use ($wordsArray) {
    $query->whereIn('name', $wordsArray);
})->simplePaginate();
```